# anacron Can't open timestamp file for job cron.daily: Permission denied

Tags: cron, kde-neon

Why is anacron failing to run jobs? I just added a weekly backup job, but it fails to run with `anacron -f`.

Here's the error in journalctl: `anacron[28209]: Can't open timestamp file for job cron.daily: Permission denied`

All the files in cron.weekly are executable (same in daily)

```
$ ll /etc/cron.weekly/
total 32
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Mar  5 00:03 ./
drwxr-xr-x 145 root root 12288 Mar  4 23:02 ../
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root   312 Oct  9  2021 0anacron*
-rwxr-xr-x   2 alex alex   329 Mar  5 00:03 backup*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  1020 Mar 17  2022 man-db*
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   102 Mar 23  2022 .placeholder
```

`anacron -T` succeeds.

`sudo run-parts --list /etc/cron.weekly/` succeeds (so does daily)

Comment: Does [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/1270943/anacron-cron-daily-not-running-my-scripts) help with the problem?

Comment: No. All the scripts in `/etc/cron*` are already executable. Funnily enough, the daily job seems to run fine today. Maybe